# sprite image replacement via link

Tags: jquery, css, css-sprites, sprite

I am looking to display a section of my sprite within a div by default, then have a text menu below the div that when different links are clicked, the section of the sprite that is displayed changes.

Here is where I am so far and have gotten my sprites all to display with the following:

**INDEX**

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<i class="sprite sprite-caramel"></i>
<i class="sprite sprite-chocolate"></i>
<i class="sprite sprite-empty"></i>
<i class="sprite sprite-strawberry"></i>
<i class="sprite sprite-vanilla"></i>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.sprite {
    background-image: url(sprite1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}

.sprite-caramel {
    width: 176px;
    height: 250px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.sprite-chocolate {
    width: 176px;
    height: 250px;
    background-position: -176px 0;
}

.sprite-empty {
    width: 176px;
    height: 250px;
    background-position: -352px 0;
}

.sprite-strawberry {
    width: 176px;
    height: 250px;
    background-position: -528px 0;
}

.sprite-vanilla {
    width: 176px;
    height: 250px;
    background-position: -704px 0;
}
```

What I would like to do is display the "empty" by default within a div, then under the div have text links with "chocolate" "vanilla" "strawberry" etc. When the link is clicked, the sprite position would then change to reflect the image of the link clicked.

I only seem to be able to find image replacement on hover when searching with google...

I am 100% new to sprites and have never used them until now.

Comment: The sprite image can be found here: http://puu.sh/3orSM.png

Comment: Do you have the set of images on hover?

Comment: Surely you want just one `sprite` element whose background is shifted in response to the controls being clicked? As it stands, every control is has class "sprite", and there's no element which will respond to the controls being clicked. This seems incorrect.

Comment: @Wind Shear I am not looking to do an on hover replacement, I want a link that when clicked the image within the div changes.

Comment: @Beetroot I am not sure of how to do this in any way and have found nothing anywhere on the web on how to do this... but yes, i want the sprite background-position to change based on what link is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need Javascript to get the job done.

**HTML**

```
<body> 
   <div id="tumbler" class="sprite sprite-empty"></div>
   <a class="flavor" data-flavor="caramel" href="#">Caramel</a>
   <a class="flavor" data-flavor="chocolate" href="#">Chocolate</a>
   <a class="flavor" data-flavor="empty" href="#">Empty</a>
   <a class="flavor" data-flavor="strawberry" href="#">Strawberry</a>
   <a class="flavor" data-flavor="vanilla" href="#">Vanilla</a>
```

**CSS**

```
 .sprite {
       background-image: url(http://puu.sh/3orSM.png);
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       display: block;
       width: 176px;
       height: 250px;
   }
   .sprite-caramel {
       background-position: 0 0;
   }
   .sprite-chocolate {
       background-position: -176px 0;
   }
   .sprite-empty {
       background-position: -352px 0;
   }
   .sprite-strawberry {
       background-position: -528px 0;
   }
   .sprite-vanilla {
       background-position: -704px 0;
   }
```

**Javascript - Requires jQuery**

```
   jQuery(document).on("ready", function() { 
      jQuery('.flavor').bind('click', function(e) {
         jQuery('#tumbler').attr('class', 'sprite sprite-' + jQuery(this).data('flavor'));
            e.stopPropagation();
         });
    });
```

**Demonstration**

And of course, the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jlratwil/GybWL/1/).

Comment: The current code only displays the sprites. What I need to do is have it display only the empty cup (within a div) then have text links below it, so if i click "chocolate" the image within the div changes from the empty cup, to the filled "chocolate" cup. I am NOT trying to do on hover, i need it done on click.

Comment: The demo works exactly how it is needed! When i move the code provided into my files and save it then try to test it on firefox, the links dont seem to change the image.

Comment: <body>
<div id="tumbler" class="sprite sprite-empty">
    </div>
 <a class="flavor" data-flavor="caramel" href="#">Caramel</a>
 <a class="flavor" data-flavor="chocolate" href="#">Chocolate</a>
 <a class="flavor" data-flavor="empty" href="#">Empty</a>
 <a class="flavor" data-flavor="strawberry" href="#">Strawberry</a>
 <a class="flavor" data-flavor="vanilla" href="#">Vanilla</a>
 <script>
jQuery('.flavor').bind('click', function(e) {
    jQuery('#tumbler').attr('class', 'sprite sprite-' + jQuery(this).data('flavor'));
    e.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
</body>

Comment: Ahh, because you have to get the jQuery file first. Put this script just above the main script. `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: WindShear's solution is cool but just to let you know that sprite offsets can be (and often are) calculated according to some simple algorithm in javascript, as opposed to hard coded in CSS, try **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/DUznZ/)** (based on WS's fiddle).