# div class replacement via link

Tags: javascript, html, css, sprite

I am looking to replace the class used by a DIV using javascript via links.

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 176px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 176px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.sprite {
    background-image: url(sprite1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}

.sprite-caramel {
    width: 176px;
    height: 250px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.sprite-chocolate {
    width: 176px;
    height: 250px;
    background-position: -176px 0;
}

.sprite-empty {
    width: 176px;
    height: 250px;
    background-position: -352px 0;
}

.sprite-strawberry {
    width: 176px;
    height: 250px;
    background-position: -528px 0;
}

.sprite-vanilla {
    width: 176px;
    height: 250px;
    background-position: -704px 0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" class="sprite sprite-empty"></div>
<ul id="wrapper">
    <li><a href="#">Chocolate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vanilla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Strawberry</a></li>
</ul>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the links below the DIV when clicked to swap the class for the assigned class to said link. So by default the div should display the class "sprite sprite-empty" then when you click the "Chocolate" link the div class changes to "sprite sprite-chocolate" etc.

Any help is appreciated ( i am totally new to sprites and have no java expierence).

**Sprite used:** http://puu.sh/3otqm.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I posted the question before, here it is

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" class="sprite sprite-empty"></div>
   <ul id="wrapper">
      <li><a href="#" class="flavor" data-flavor="chocolate">Chocolate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="flavor" data-flavor="vanilla">Vanilla</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="flavor" data-flavor="strawberry">Strawberry</a></li>
   </ul>
</body>
```

The data-* attribute is perfectly valid in HTML 5.

**Javascript - requires jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).on("ready", function() { 
   jQuery('.flavor').bind('click', function(e) {
      jQuery('#container').attr('class', 'sprite sprite-' + jQuery(this).data('flavor'));
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

**Demo**

And yes, [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jlratwil/GybWL/2/).

Comment: Which "question before"? The OP doesn't have a jQuery tag. If it did, you should explain the use of the flavor class and data attribute and provide a reason to stop propagation.

Comment: @RobG, I refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310489/sprite-image-replacement-via-link

Answer (score 2):

Use this jQuery (need to reference jQuery library)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $("#wrapper a").on("click", function () {
             var selected_sprite = $(this).data("sprite");
             $("#container").attr("class", "sprite " + selected_sprite);
         });
     });
</script>
```

Then add the data attribute to each of your links like this:

```
<ul id="wrapper">
   <li><a href="#" data-sprite="sprite-chocolate">Chocolate</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-sprite="sprite-vanilla">Vanilla</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-sprite="sprite-strawberry">Strawberry</a></li>
</ul>
```

That should do the trick.